# SQL multirow data on one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I almost never ask a question, so please be patient with me.

Example `Orders` table:

| Order_ID | Ord_Partno | Ord_UnitPrice | Ord_Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1658712 | PN001 | $1.20 | 9 |
| 1658712 | PN002 | $2.40 | 4 |
| 1658712 | PN003 | $1.40 | 21 |
| 1658712 | PN004 | $1.10 | 16 |

Example `Inventory` table:

| Inv_Partno | Inv_Warehouse | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PN001 | Atlanta | 14 |
| PN001 | AtlantaHold | 0 |
| PN001 | Chicago | 7 |
| PN001 | ChicagoHold | 0 |
| PN002 | Atlanta | 5 |
| PN002 | AtlantaHold | 18 |
| PN002 | Chicago | 0 |
| PN002 | ChicagoHold | 0 |
| PN003 | Atlanta | 2 |
| PN003 | AtlantaHold | 43 |
| PN003 | Chicago | 19 |
| PN003 | ChicagoHold | 0 |

In this example, each part in Inventory has 4 warehouse entries. The actual stock available, and the amount in Holding for other orders. If either warehouse (Atlanta or Chicago, NOT Hold) has more stock than Ord_Qty (but not combined), I would like to get following result given an Order_ID:

| Ord_Partno | Ord_UnitPrice | Ord_Qty | Atlanta | Chicago | InStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PN001 | $1.20 | 9 | 14 | 7 | Yes |
| PN002 | $2.40 | 4 | 5 | 0 | Yes |
| PN003 | $1.40 | 21 | 2 | 19 | No |
| PN004 | $1.10 | 16 | 8 | 9 | No |

As a beginner I have not been able to replicate this result.
I have tried using DISTINCT, LEFT/INNER JOIN, CASE + EXISTS ect.
Could anyone help me out with this?

Example query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Ord_Partno, Ord_UnitPrice, Ord_Qty, 
    () AS Atlanta, () AS Chicago, () AS InStock 
FROM 
    Orders 
INNER JOIN 
    Inventory ON Ord_Partno = Inv_Partno
WHERE
    Order_ID = 1658712 
    AND (Inv_Warehouse = "Atlanta" OR Inv_Warehouse = "Chicago")
```

Comment: Please mention your DBMS name.

Comment: @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur
I believe the DBMS is MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Ord_Partno, Ord_UnitPrice, Ord_Qty, 
    COALESCE(AtlantaInv.Stock, 0) AS Atlanta,
    COALESCE(ChicagoInv.Stock, 0) AS Chicago,
    case when (AtlantaInv.Stock >= Ord_Qty OR ChicagoInv.Stock >= Ord_Qty) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as InStock
FROM 
    Orders 
LEFT JOIN 
    Inventory AS AtlantaInv ON Ord_Partno = AtlantaInv.Inv_Partno and AtlantaInv.Inv_Warehouse = 'Atlanta'
LEFT JOIN 
    Inventory AS ChicagoInv ON Ord_Partno = ChicagoInv.Inv_Partno and ChicagoInv.Inv_Warehouse = 'Chicago'
```

Answer (score 1):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table orders (Order_ID int, Ord_Partno varchar(50), Ord_UnitPrice float, Ord_Qty int);
 insert into orders values(1658712, 'PN001',    1.20,   9);
 insert into orders values(1658712, 'PN002',    2.40,   4);
 insert into orders values(1658712, 'PN003',    1.40,   21);
 insert into orders values(1658712, 'PN004',    1.10,   16);
 
 create table Inventory(Inv_Partno varchar(50), Inv_Warehouse varchar(100), Stock int);
 insert into Inventory values('PN001','Atlanta',    14);
 insert into Inventory values('PN001','AtlantaHold',    0);
 insert into Inventory values('PN001','Chicago',    7);
 insert into Inventory values('PN001','ChicagoHold',    0);
 insert into Inventory values('PN002','Atlanta',    5);
 insert into Inventory values('PN002','AtlantaHold',    18);
 insert into Inventory values('PN002','Chicago',    0);
 insert into Inventory values('PN002','ChicagoHold',    0);
 insert into Inventory values('PN003','Atlanta',    2);
 insert into Inventory values('PN003','AtlantaHold',    43);
 insert into Inventory values('PN003','Chicago',    19);
 insert into Inventory values('PN003','ChicagoHold',    0);
```

Query:

```
 select Ord_Partno, Ord_UnitPrice,Ord_Qty,sum(case when Inv_Warehouse ='Atlanta' then Stock else 0 end)'Atlanta',
 sum(case when Inv_Warehouse ='Chicago' then Stock else 0 end)'Chicago',
 (case when Ord_Qty>sum(case when Inv_Warehouse ='Atlanta' then Stock else 0 end) and Ord_Qty>sum(case when Inv_Warehouse ='Chicago' then Stock else 0 end) then 'No' else 'Yes' end)InStock
 from
 orders ord
 left join Inventory inv on ord.Ord_Partno=inv.Inv_Partno
 group by Ord_Partno, Ord_UnitPrice, Ord_Qty
```

Output:

| Ord_Partno | Ord_UnitPrice | Ord_Qty | Atlanta | Chicago | InStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PN001 | 1.2 | 9 | 14 | 7 | Yes |
| PN002 | 2.4 | 4 | 5 | 0 | Yes |
| PN003 | 1.4 | 21 | 2 | 19 | No |
| PN004 | 1.1 | 16 | 0 | 0 | No |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5adf3dbcd57d0cbaa9682b587ed6b713)*

Comment: This is excellent, thank you very very much for your effort.

Comment: @PatrickBailey you are most welcome. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

The hold part is what is going to get more annoying if you need to build this out longer, but this is a strong case for sum and case built together.

```
select ord_partno, ord_unitPrice, Ord_qty,
sum(case when inv_warehouse = 'atlanta' then stock else 0 end) as [Atlanta],
sum(case when inv_warehouse = 'Chicago' then stock else 0 end) as [Chicago],
case when (sum(case when inv_warehouse not like '%hold' then stock else 0 end)) - (sum(case when inv_warehouse like '%hold' then stock else 0 end)) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as InStock
from
order
inner join inventory on ord_partno = invpartno
where order_id = 1658712
group by ord_partno, ord_unitPrice, Ord_qty
```